# How do I solve a null exception when I try to create an adapter in MvvmCross Bluetooth-LE (Xamarin Forms)?

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

```cs
var adapter = Mvx.Resolve<MvvmCross.Plugins.BLE.Bluetooth.LE.IAdapter>();
App.SetAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm trying to use the BLE Plugin for MvvMCross but it returns a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install package (the plugin) in each project. The PCL, the Android and the iOS project. The Android and iOS packages create a bootstrap class which loads the plugin. Please ensure, that you also add the permissions to your AndroidManifest.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

We will add this to the documentation with the 1.0 release. Please ensure that you call `Mvx.Resolve` **after** `LoadApplication(...)`. Before this call, the Plugin will not be loaded and you can't resolve `IAdapter` or any other MvvMCross interface.

Comment: I already have installed in each project, also I've included all permissions, but it's still not working

Comment: where does the exception occur? Can you provide a call stack? What does `App.SetAdapter`? Where is it located?

Comment: Please ensure that you call `Mvx.Resolve` **after** `LoadApplication(...)`. Before this call, the Plugin will not be loaded.

Comment: I have this method im my App.cs
`public static void SetAdapter(IAdapter adapter)
        {
            Adapter = adapter;
        }`

Comment: and the `Mvx.Resolve` is in my MainActivity.cs after `LoadApplication` @Sven-Michael

Comment: **An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MvvmCross.Platform.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
That's the error message

Comment: Can you try to resolve it in on of you Pages? Or upload it somewhere? I guess it has something to do with the life cycle not the the plugin it self. It hasn't been initialized when you try to resolve it.

Comment: I've tried to resolve on the pages and it didn't work too, is there any method to initialize the plugin?

Comment: No if everything installed ind initialized properly, it should come out of the box ^^

Comment: Can I send my code to you by email? I really need help on that

Comment: You can upload it to dropbox or some other filehoster.

Comment: [Projeto Permeabilidade do Solo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpm5qgoq7eamn5t/PermeabilidadeSolo.zip?dl=0)
That's a VS 2015 project @Sven-Michael

Comment: OK. You are not using MvvMCross Forms :) So the complete MvvmCross is not initialized. It seems that you want to use it without MvvmCross. We are currently working on the non MvvmCross version. So for now, you have to use MvvmCross Forms: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms

Comment: So, I was using MvvmCross and I must use MvvmCross.Forms?

Comment: Both ;) MvvmCross forms is the package that adds forms support. Have a detailed look at the sample project on the linked page for the setup.